# Terminate application AND call the destructors of local objects

Tags: c++, windows, stack, destructor, exit

I have some objects on the stack in main function:

```
int main(...)
{
   CFoo foo;
   CBar bar;
}
```

Also, I have a function, that keeps track of errors in my application:

```
void Err(std::string msg)
{
   SomehowLogErrorMessage(msg);
   exit(1);
}
```

Err function is definitely useful when I have to report a fatal error. I just log the error and terminate the application - it cannot recover after such errors. However, terminating with "exit()" does not invoke foo and bar destructors - a behavior, that I actually expected (but was wrong). "abort()" doesn't help either. Also, **I cannot use exceptions** to catch them in main(). Is there any other way to implement Err function so, that it terminates the app and correctly cleans the stack objects? Or should I somehow redesign my error handling?

Thanks!

---

p.s. By the way, can't I send WM_QUIT message to my main window? I am not good with WinAPI, but my app is pure Win32 and my Err() function can get a handle to my main window. Will it work?

Comment: Obvious, stupid question, but why can't you use exceptions?

Comment: If you can't throw an exception (why not?) the other option is to return an error code, and then propagate that back all the way to the end of main.

Comment: Let's say, platform-specific restrictions. Project is compiled with -fno-exceptions flag.

Comment: If it is important, I would like to add, that I don't care about local objects of the entire call stack, I would like to clean only objects in main(). I am not sure whether it is possible now...

Comment: "Project is compiled with `-fno-exceptions` flag" = project is not actually using C++, a language which requires support for exceptions.

Comment: C++ is so flexible, that it cannot *require* anything. Especially exceptions. Take a look around - how many C++ games for Sony Playstation or apps for Android phones use exceptions? I guess, none. p.s. sorry for trolling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not without exceptions or returning normally from Err all the way up the callstack. You need to unwind the stack.

Answer (score 2):

There's still C's `setjmp` and `longjmp`. It should bring you back to `main`, so the program would terminate as usual after leaving scope of `main`, in which case C++'s destructor mechanism will destroy your local objects in `main`.

Of course using `longjmp` is frowned upon in C++ for good reasons. It will skip any other functions on the stack, so it really works only for a few stack objects in `main`.

It might be easier to allocate your objects on the heap and `delete` them manually in `Err`.

Comment: And also skip the ones between Err and main (not in the requirement? :-)

Comment: Well, it would be terrible, but at least it would get us back to Main() ... I really would re-design my error handling if I was the OP rather than hacking around.

Comment: I don't think it's safe to say a C runtime function will call destructors. Even the manpage says register and automatic variables will have undefined values.

Answer (score 2):

There are basically two methods for propagating errors around in C++: Exceptions (which you've seemingly arbitrarily excluded) and return codes.

Since you can't use exceptions, you're going to need to start passing return codes from your functions that may fail and test them to see if you need to stop and return back up to main. If you don't unwind the stack like this there's no way to guarantee that destructors will be called properly.

Also consider that if your program is in a fatal state will destructors actually be able to clean up expectedly? What if the object state is flawed and can't be taken down properly? Instead of calling exit you could call `abort` which would at least leave a core to help diagnose the problem if you get into a bad state. For fatal errors where exceptions are unavailable this is a reasonable choice.

Comment: Well, program is not in the fatal state (nothing is corrupted). But the subsequent work is pointless, that's why I was looking for a way to exit right here and right now. And I was hoping to avoid a pack of unnecessary return-value-check-and-propagate code...

Comment: In other words, "I want exactly what exceptions offer, but I can't use exceptions"

Answer (score 1):

I would redesign your error handling.  The most straightforward thing to do is return control to `main`, and let it do its normal cleanup.  Exceptions provide this capability through stack unwinding, but you can't use exceptions.  OK, that's fine.  Sometimes you just can't use exceptions.

So instead of having `Err` try to shut the program down, have `Err` log the error and return an error code.  Ideally, `Err` shouldn't be doing two jobs anyway, which you're trying to have it do:  1) Log the error, 2) Terminate the app gracefully.

If your application happens to be multithreaded, you might have a failrly easy out.  In the error-logging thread, signal a "die" event.  Have the main thread wait on this event along with whatever else it waits on (or inject a job to it via `QueueUserAPC` or similar).  When the event is signaled, shut the app down.

Comment: That would force me to analyze error code all the way up the call stack. That's what I was trying to avoid, now I guess it is impossible for C++. Worse, Err() can be called inside object constructor - and how can I pass error code from there?

Answer (score 0):

I believe `Exit` will terminate the application immediately. To see the behavior you are expecting `foo` and `bar` would have to go out of scope.  That means the main function would have to end normally with a return value. Instead of calling `Exit()` out of your Err function you need to find a way to return to your main function and let it return normally with an error value.